# Multibinding: two columns to one column

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, .net-3.5, multibinding

I have a table which has two columns `ValueA` and `ValueB`. I need to show the table in a grid, but I need to show either `ValueA` or `ValueB`, but not both. So if `ValueA` doesn't have a value, then `ValueB` is shown and vice versa. When user enters a value to the column, only `ValueA` should be updated. So `ValueB` in kind of a default value (it's update in another part of the program).

I've tried to resolve this problem using `MultiBinding`, but I've only managed to *show* the values. The value user enters to the grid always gets overwritten by the original value.

I have created a converter named `ValueAValueBConverter` that has a Convert method like this:

```
public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
    if (values[0] != DependencyProperty.UnsetValue && values[0] != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(values[0].ToString()))
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("values 0: " + values[0]);
        return values[0].ToString();
    }
    if (values[1] != DependencyProperty.UnsetValue && values[1] != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(values[1].ToString()))
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("values 1: " + values[1]);
        return values[1].ToString();
    }

    return null;
}
```

And a ConvertBack method (which never gets called):

```
public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
    return new object [] { value, value };
}
```

The XAML of the bound colums looks like this:

```
<toolkit:DataGridTextColumn Width="2*" Header="{x:Static localProperties:Resources.TValuesAB}">
    <toolkit:DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource myValueAValueBConverter}" Mode="TwoWay">
            <Binding Path="ValueA" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" />
            <Binding Path="ValueB" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </toolkit:DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
</toolkit:DataGridTextColumn>
```

Should I do this in the ViewModel (we're using MVVM pattern) or is there any other way to do this with XAML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I well understood, you just need one attribute more in your class, something like ValueAorB. With a getter which will do the work your Converter does and a setter a bit more complicated.

```
public object ValueAorB
{
    get
    {
        if (values[0] != DependencyProperty.UnsetValue && values[0] != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(values[0].ToString()))
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("values 0: " + values[0]);
            return values[0].ToString();
        }
        if (values[1] != DependencyProperty.UnsetValue && values[1] != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(values[1].ToString()))
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("values 1: " + values[1]);
            return values[1].ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Don't forget to make it raises the PropertyChanged event.

And with that:

> And a ConvertBack method (which never gets called):

May be you don't need a setter. Think about it. A two way will be more complicated and you don't even need it. In addition, I think you could do it with your own method if you were trying to make it one way.

Comment: This solution works. The ConvertBack method being never called was not intentional, so I needed to add a setter also.

Answer (score 0):

your code works fine, just change the ConvertBack method to return the value into ValueA ,and Binding.DoNothing to ValueB. so the user will be able to change ValueA only :

```
 public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return new object[] { value, Binding.DoNothing };
    }
```